# Firefox add-on that replaces embedded YouTube video with default thumbnail

Tags: firefox, youtube

In some non-YouTube webpages there are YouTube embedded videos.  Usually pressing a "play" button within them will make them play.  Associated with each of those videos there are [several thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api), one of which is the "default".

I am looking for a Firefox extension (though I suspect it doesn't exist) that, when Firefox loads the page, makes it so that instead of getting a webpage with an embedded YouTube video, I get instead the same webpage with the default thumbnail for that video --- as an image, not as an embedded video --- in the same place (and taking up the same space) as the embedded video used to have.

In other words, is there a Firefox add-on that replaces an embedded YouTube video with its default thumbnail?